# materialbox Materializecss works only after typing initialization jQuery in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

I have used '.materialboxed' in my webpage, but the initialization in script doesn't work, I have to manually type `$('.materialboxed').materialbox();` in console for it to work.

Html (ui-view in angular route)

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="card-panel col l12" style="height: 750px;">
            <img class="col l5 materialboxed" height="500px" id="poster"
                 ng-src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{{poster_path}}"/>

            <div class="col l7">
                <div class="row">
                    <a class="col l10" style="float:left;text-align: left;" ng-href="{{homepage}}">
                        <h3 class="title" ng-bind="original_title"></h3>
                    </a>
                    <a ng-href="http://www.imdb.com/title/{{imdb_link}}"
                       style="float:right;text-align: right; margin-top: 29px;"
                       class="imdb-link col l2" title="IMDb"><i class="icon-imdb"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="row"><p ng-bind="overview"></p>
                    <span class="right" ng-bind="release_date"></span>
                    <h5>Genres</h5>

                    <p ng-bind="genre"></p>
                    <h5>Production Companies</h5>

                    <p ng-bind="names">
                    </p>

                    <h5>Voting</h5>

                    <p ng-bind="vote_average"></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See the  in 3rd line.

index.html

```
//rest code 
<main ui-view></main>
</div>
<script src="js/angular_min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angucomplete-alt.js"></script>
<script src="appRoute.js"></script>
<script src="controller/MovieController.js"></script>
<script src="controller/LoginController.js"></script>
<script src="controller/RegisterController.js"></script>
<script src="controller/TvController.js"></script>
<script src="controller/LoggedInController.js"></script>
<script src="controller/TopMovieController.js"></script>
<script src="app-services/DetailsService.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
                    menuWidth: 300,
                    edge: 'left',
                    closeOnClick: true
                }
        );
        $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
        $("#movie").click(function () {
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname + "#/movie";
        });
        $("#tv").click(function () {
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname + "#/tv";
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Even after initializing the materialboxed, it doesn't work. It works only after typing `$('.materialboxed').materialbox();` in console manually.

Help me figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `$(document).ready` in Angular. In fact you should try to use as little jQuery as possible, but if you need to, then you should create a directive that allows you to initialize the function after they render.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last)
      setTimeout(function() {
        scope.$emit('onRepeatLast', element, attrs);
    }, 1);
  };
});

app.controller('MoviesController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
  });
}
```

Now you can apply this to your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <!-- this is just an example with the added directive -->
  <li ng-repeat="movie in movies" on-last-repeat>
    <img ng-src="{{imageObjectHere}}" class="materialboxed">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since you added this new directive in there, the `$('.materialboxed').materialbox();` should fire after the repeat is done